# Trying to get the minimum value from a dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a dict and variable:

```
Dictionary<int, string> minDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
decimal min;
```

Then dict is filled with the values...

I trying to get the first value and compare with the others:

```
min = Convert.ToDecimal(minDict.Values.First());
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in minDict)
{
    if (Convert.ToDecimal(kvp.Value[kvp.Key]) < min)
        min = Convert.ToDecimal(kvp.Value[kvp.Key]);
}
```

But I have an error, when compare variables (<) `Invalid cast from 'Char' to 'Decimal'.`

Comment: Do you want to get the minimum value of the dictionary ? or minimum keyValuePair ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already iterating over key-value pairs so you don't need to use the indexer:

```
min = Convert.ToDecimal(minDict.Values.First());
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in mininDict)
{
    if (Convert.ToDecimal(kvp.Value) < min) min = Convert.ToDecimal(kvp.Value);
}
```

Also here's how you can do it with LINQ:

```
var min = minDict.Select(item => Convert.ToDecimal(item.Value)).Min();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
decimal min = minDict.Values.Select(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s)).Min();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
kvp.Value[kvp.Key]
```

This does not make sense. kvp.Value already *is* the value. If you only use kvp.Value without the indexer, it should work.